# Double of, double than. Triple of, triple than

Tags: word-choice

Googling those expression between quotes does not help (about the same number of occurrences). Do Double/triple use "than" or "of" after them?

eg: the monthly-averaged discharges flowing through that river are as nearly as triple than/of those flowing in the Mississippi river

Comment: the monthly-averaged discharges flowing through that river are nearly a triple of those flowing in the Mississippi river

Comment: @alwayslearning "**a triple**" is a set of three things, like "**a triple whammy**", but "**triple**" is a multiplier, like "**three times the flow**".

Comment: 'they are nearly triple those flowing in the river'

Answer (score 2):

Neither - there are too many words. I suggest:

> The monthly-averaged discharges flowing through that river are
>   **<del>[as]</del>** nearly **<del>[as]</del>** triple **<del>[than/of]</del>** those
>   flowing in the Mississippi river.

Giving

> The monthly-averaged discharges flowing through that river are nearly
>   triple those flowing in the Mississippi river.